# Can I create a nice box shadow with CSS < 3?

Tags: css

I bet CSS3 is not compatible to all browsers.

I want to know if there is any method I can create a box shadow with using only CSS and none of the CSS3 methods.

It should be as good looking as made using CSS3, so that I can make my application compatible across all browsers.

Comment: with CSS2 you can do it with a combination of divs and images, x-browser compatible, but obviously not as *elegant* or simple as with CSS3.

Comment: then whats the alternative if I want to make it all-browser compatible?

Comment: As I said, the CSS2 div + image solution is x-browser (cross browser) note that *all* is a stretch! you can never target all browsers, at least the most popular.

Comment: then i guess CSS3 will help in targetting lot of browsers?

Comment: CSS3 will only target browsers that support it, just the more "recent". To answer your question (again), you can achieve that by using CSS2 (via images and divs), that will cover a great deal of browsers, more than CSS3 compatible browsers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you cannot. You'll need to use images when CSS3 is not available.

Answer (score 1):

No, CSS box shadows are not supported in most older browsers that you would need to support.  Plan for graceful degradation.  IE unfortunately still has the majority of market share and most people are not on the latest version.  Decide what your lowest common denominator is and what is acceptable for them to see.  People using an older browser just aren't getting the same experience as everyone else, but you can make sure they see the most important details.  Consider something like the following to customize what each browser sees. It's a pain, but I think it is the best option.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen, projection" href="/_/css/ie.css" />
<![endif]-->
<!--[if lt IE 8]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen, projection" href="/_/css/ie7.css" />
<![endif]-->
<!--[if lt IE 7]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen, projection" href="/_/css/ie6.css" />
<![endif]-->
```